# How to take my local commits from master and place them in a new branch

Tags: git, branch, commit

I've created some changes to a git repo, and committed them to master (I have *NOT* pushed the changes up to GitHub, however). What I need to do now, is create a new branch, and move my commits over to this new branch. The changes are quite large and so manually redoing the changes on a new branch is not possible - hopefully there is some set of commands which will rewind master to before my commits, move my commits onto a new branch, and then push these up.

I did search for other questions but I didn't see any that exactly fitted my situation, so wanted to get an exact answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fairly easy:

```sh
# make sure you're on master
git checkout master
# create a new branch that is identical to master
git branch mystuff master
# reset your local master branch to the state of the remote master
git reset --hard origin/master
# push your new branch to the remote
git push origin mystuff
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly - Fernaref's may have also worked but since this seemed easier I tried this first :P

Comment: Yea, it is easier when the commit you want to roll back to is the current HEAD of origin/master.

Answer (score 1):

First, create the new branch, then rewind master:

```
git branch new_branch
git reset --hard <sha1-id>
```

To find the needed sha1-id, check `git log`.

Afterwards, you can push that branch up to your remote:

```
git checkout new_branch
git push -u origin new_branch
```

Note that `-u` will set up a tracking branch, meaning you will be able to issue `git pull` and `git push` without specifing `origin new_branch` from now on.